# Can I use Expresso with pCloudy?

Tags: python, android, testing, appium, expresso

I've been researching various testing frameworks recently, and Expresso has caught my attention due to its features and capabilities.

I'm currently considering how it might fit into our existing infrastructure, particularly with tools we're already using. One of the platforms we frequently utilize is pCloudy. Given this, I wanted to understand the compatibility and integration possibilities between the two.

Can I seamlessly integrate and use Expresso with pCloudy for comprehensive testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Espresso is an Android testing framework designed to synchronize test actions automatically with your app's user interface. This platform offers the capability to craft concise and dependable Android UI tests. Additionally, it ensures that tests only proceed once all background processes are complete.

Upon completion of the test runs, comprehensive reports are generated. After the automation process concludes, the device used for testing is automatically made available for subsequent use by you or other team members.

There are two methods to execute Espresso test cases on pCloudy:

Through the pCloudy User Interface Dashboard.
By utilizing the pCloudy Utility or the Espresso Orchestrator

Attaching both the links to learn more :

1. https://www.pcloudy.com/docs/espresso-ui
2. https://www.pcloudy.com/docs/espresso-orchestrator-1